# jquery ui-menu plugins

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

All,

Is there any light tool in jquery which produces a menu like tipsy tooltip or jgrowl with onclick event

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Any help here?

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/Plugins/category/44